# Cascading tabhosts: how do I maintain addressability?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have an architecture which simulates a treeview structure using a spinner supported by a tabhost. The first spinner is not enabled and the first tabhost shows up to 10 tabs. Selecting any one of the tabs exposes a spinner filled with selectable items and a subordinate tabhost with tabs unique to that selection 'thread'. This structure is repeatable ad infinitum.

The display of this structure is working flawlessly, as far as I can tell. I say that because my application goes to a forced close whenever I click on a 3rd-level spinner. The error log reports a message from WindowManager: 'Attempted to add a window with unknown token. Aborting'

I believe it is notable that this spinner is the first control element that is located in the 2nd FrameLayout!

Does anyone have an idea how to work around this apparent addressability problem?

PS: This application is an attempt to port a web application to the android platform. A demonstration is available at georgiansoftware.com [username:Guest / password:Guest2009]

Comment: Basically, the question is: How do you popup a spinner message in a tabhost view?

Comment: paste some code here. how do you create and display the spinner that crashes your app?

Comment: `Spinner availabilityToggle = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.availabilityToggle);
  final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> availabilityToggler = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
    HomeGroup.group, R.array.availabilityArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
  availabilityToggler.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line );
  availabilityToggle.setAdapter(availabilityToggler);`   where HomeGroup.this is the context of the tabgroup